# I want to add legend to my ggplot and give two separate headings in the legend, one for green lines and other for red lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I simply wanted to add legend to my graph. I have tried various approaches but I have not been successful so far. There is one solid red line, 2 broken red lines, one solid green line and two broken green lines, and circles. For Red lines, I want to give them a separate heading and for green lines, I want to give them a separate heading in the legend.

```
VPCplot <- ggplot(Tab, aes(x=TIME, y=DV))+ geom_point (size=2.5, colour='black',shape=1)+
geom_line(data=VPC1, aes(x=TIME, y=ObservedMean), color='red', size=1)+
geom_line(data=VPC1, aes(x=TIME, y=observedpercentileLL), color='red', size=1, linetype = "dashed")+
geom_line(data=VPC1, aes(x=TIME, y=observedpercentileUL), color='red', size=1, linetype = "dashed")+
geom_line(data=VPC1, aes(x=TIME, y=SimulationMean), color='green', size=1)+
geom_line(data=VPC1, aes(x=TIME, y=simulatedpercentileLL), color='green', size=1, linetype = 
"dashed")+
geom_line(data=VPC1, aes(x=TIME, y=simulatedpercentileUL), color='green', size=1, linetype = 
"dashed")+
xlab("Time (Hours)") +
ylab("THC Concentration (ng/mL)")+
ggtitle("VPC_Two Compartment PK Model")

VPCplot + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
             plot.margin = margin(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, "cm"),
             plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey90",colour = "black",size = 5)) +
theme(axis.text = element_text(colour = "red", size = rel(1)),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 14,face = "bold"),
    axis.title.x= element_text(size = 18),  
    axis.title.y= element_text(size = 18),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size = 18,face = "bold"))
```

[image: This is how my plot looks like]

[image: This is how my dataset looks like]

Comment: Please do not post images of your data, we can't load those to try things out.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is in the wide (or matrix) form, works well for base R but for ggplot it's better to convert them to long.

Since I do not have your data, I simulated some data below and commented on where the conversion happens...

And ideally, you should do dput(Tab) and dput(VPC1), have these data frames on as part of the code so others can try and give you suggestions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#simulate some data
TIME = 1:50
SHIFT = 0.2
Tab = data.frame(TIME=sample(TIME,100,replace=T))
Tab$DV = 1/Tab$TIME + rnorm(100,0,0.2)
VPC1 = data.frame(
       TIME = TIME,
       SimulationMean = 1/TIME,
       simulatedpercentileUL = 1/TIME+0.05,
       simulatedpercentileLL = 1/TIME-0.05,
       ObservedMean = 1/TIME + SHIFT,
       observedpercentileUL = 1/TIME + SHIFT +0.05,
       observedpercentileLL = 1/TIME + SHIFT -0.05
)

# here we convert it into long, and time is the identifying variable
# we also introduce a class observed or simulated so that
# the UL,LL and mean lines will have same colour
VPC1 <- VPC1 %>% pivot_longer(-TIME) %>% 
mutate(type=ifelse(grepl("Observed",name,ignore.case=TRUE),"Observed","Simulated"))

# create separate data frames for UL, LL and the means (VPC1)
UL <- VPC1 %>% filter( grepl("percentileUL",name))
LL <- VPC1 %>% filter( grepl("percentileLL",name))
VPC1 <- VPC1 %>% filter( !grepl("percentile",name))

# plot, very similar to what you have before
VPCplot <- ggplot(Tab, aes(x=TIME, y=DV))+ 
geom_point (size=2.5, colour='black',shape=1)+
geom_line(data=VPC1, aes(x=TIME, y=value,col=type))+
geom_line(data=UL, aes(x=TIME, y=value,col=type),linetype="dotted")+
geom_line(data=LL, aes(x=TIME, y=value,col=type),linetype="dotted")+
### specify the colors here
scale_color_manual(name="Type",values=c("red","green"))
```

[image]